# Is there a way to dynamically position multiple images in excel using python without specifying row and column?

Tags: python, automation, export-to-excel

I am currently using xlsxwriter to export multiple images and graphs to an excel file. Right now, I am specifying the anchor for the same by specifying row and column manually to place them one after another.
Is there a way that I can automate this process and write down a code that identifies where an image starts or ends automatically and place the next image accordingly?
For Example:

```
worksheet.insert_image('B2', 'python.png')
```

So that I don't have to specify column and row like 'B2' in the above code snippet.